# CloudFormation - Is it possible to define a mapping for a generic and reused resource definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to make a cloud formation template to create a large number of dynamoDB tables. I understand how to map the AttributeDefintions to variables, but is it possible to create a single resource definition and then re-use that with mapped variables? Or must I declare each resource (table) statically?

This is an example of what I have for 4 tables, was hoping to condense this by re-using the resource definition rather than statically listing the block 4 times

```
Parameters:
  ReadCapacityUnits:
    Type: String
    Default: "2"
  WriteCapacityUnits:
    Type: String
    Default: "2"
Resources:
  DynamoTableTotalCountsHour:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacityUnits
        WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacityUnits
      TableName: TotalCountsHour
  DynamoTableTotalCountsDay:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacityUnits
        WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacityUnits
      TableName: TotalCountsDay
  DynamoTableTotalCountsMonth:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacityUnits
        WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacityUnits
      TableName: TotalCountsMonth
  DynamoTableTotalCountsYear:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "UserId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "RangeId"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacityUnits
        WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacityUnits
      TableName: TotalCountsYear
```

Comment: I recommend using [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) which is a CF DSL in python, you will get all the goodness of a real programming language(hello loops, good bye yaml and json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no loop function with CloudFormation itself.

You could use [Nested Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) to reuse the DynamoDB definition and minimise the amount of duplicated code.

For example call one stack from another:

```
Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
       Parameters:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 2
          WriteCapacityUnits: 2
       TemplateURL: Url-of-S3-Bucket-with-DynamoDB-Template-Stack
```

Note that using nested stacks with many tables does mean that you are at risk of having to delete/replace all your DynamoDB tables at the same time should you need to make some types of update to the stack.

If you don't want a dependency between the builds of DynamoDB tables, then use a template stack with an external orchestration engine to loop through the parameters and repeatedly call the AWS CloudFormation API.